# Android Studio MainActivity.kt can't reference ids in main_activity.xml

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-activity

I am new to Android Studio. I wrote a simple code in the `main_activity.xml` file, with `ids`. But when I try to reference the `ids` from my `MainActivity.kt` file. It shows an error `Unresolved reference: btnDatePicker` i.e an unresolved error.

I don't know what wrong. Here's a screenshot of my `MainActivity.kt` file. As you can see, when I try to call the `id` btnDatePicker, it returns an error.
[image]

And Here's a screenshot of my `activity_main.xml`, as you'll see I have circled the particular `id` I'm trying to reference.

[image]

Comment: Why do you even think that you can access it like this?

Comment: @IvoBeckers I'm coming from Python KivyMD, I usually do something similar, a bit different though, and I was following a tutorial from a year ago, He did this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to rebuild project,**Build -> Rebuild project**
We have *2 variant* and I recommend it. I recommend you use [View Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding). Because Koltin synthetic(just writing id element) is deprecated.

To enable view binding in a module, set the **viewBinding** build option to **true** in the module-level **build.gradle** file, as shown in the following example:

```
android {
...
buildFeatures {
    viewBinding = true
}
```

}

**Usage**

```
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding 
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
binding = ActivityMainBinding(layoutInflater)
val view = binding.root
setContentView(view)
}
```

then use your xml elements

```
binding.btnDataPicker.setOnClickListener {
   ...
}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand youe first sentence, does the project rebuild affect the view binding.

Comment: And please @Madi where ashould I add the **USAGE** code to??

Comment: @Edwin use in your MainActivity.kt

Comment: @Edwin sometimes it depends on build, but still recommend using ViewBinding it's easy ;)

Comment: thanks for your Help, I've a bit helpful video on youtube, it's not quite clear, but I hope with time it will be..

Answer (score 2):

Id cannot be referenced directly

Under normal conditions, you can bind the control using the following code:

```
val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnDatePicker)
```

and if you want to use id directly, i think this article can help you
[View Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding)

Answer (score 0):

Just add this in your gradle file in plugins id 'kotlin-android-extensions'

Comment: It's not recommended to use `kotlin-android-extensions` anymore, because it is a deprecated lib that will be removed from Kotlin soon
https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2022/02/discontinuing-kotlin-synthetics-for-views.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @BecirKoljenovic I am using view and data binding, there's no need for kotlin exytensions. Thanks for feedback..

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31157548)

Answer (score 0):

plugins {
id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}

Just add this in your gradle file in plugins id 'kotlin-android-extensions'